# Constrain/center CAEmitterLayer even after device rotation

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In Swift Playgrounds for iPad, I am having difficulty constraining CAEmitterLayer instance to the center permanently. For example, it stays centered until the device is rotated, so I need to find some way to constrain it to the center for all device orientations.

Here is what I have so far, keep in mind I’ve tried adding observers to device orientation with no avail. But this could just be an error on my part. Thanks!

```
emitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y)

let cell = CAEmitterCell()
cell.birthRate = 25
cell.lifetime = 30
cell.velocity = 250
cell.velocityRange = 250
cell.spinRange = 5
cell.scale = 0.04
cell.scaleRange = 0.03
cell.alphaSpeed = -0.15
cell.emissionRange = CGFloat.pi * 2
cell.contents = UIImage(named: "RainbowApple")?.cgImage

emitterLayer.emitterCells = [cell]
emitterLayer.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
emitterLayer.zPosition = -1
view.layer.addSublayer(emitterLayer)

emitterLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 1)
emitterLayer.renderMode = CAEmitterLayerRenderMode.oldestLast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALayer does not support constraints.  It looks like you want to do this in a UIViewController so move the line `emitterLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.center.y)` into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which gets called every time your views bounds change (ie during rotation).  This will always keep your emitter in the center, even if the center changes for another reason, such as split screen multitasking on iPad.